# Add description to custom text widget and display the 5 recent post titles

Tags: widgets, text, description

I am running into a problem where I have no idea where to add in a description so it will show up on the widget dashboard. It just keeps displaying the title.

Something else I would love some help with is to add functionality to display the 5 most recent post titles (all categories) and I also do not know how to do that. I will post the code I have now below. Any input will greatly help my web design education.

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Kevins Textbox
Plugin URI: 
Description: A text widget created by Kevin Ullyott for practice in creating widgets
Author: Kevin Ullyott
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://modmacro.com/
*/


class kevintext extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name='Kevins Textbox');
        array('description' => __('A text widget created by Kevin Ullyott for practice in creating widgets') );
    }


    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {


        extract( $args );

        $headline = $instance['headline'];      
        $text = $instance['text'];      



        echo $before_widget;

        echo $before_title;

        echo "<p class=\"headline\">$headline</p>";

        echo $after_title;

        echo "<p class=\"text\">$text</p>";

        echo $after_widget;


    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['headline'] = ( $new_instance['headline'] );
        $instance['text'] = ( $new_instance['text'] );
        return $instance;
    }


    public function form( $instance ) {

        $headline = $instance[ 'headline' ];
        $text = $instance[ 'text' ];

        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Headline:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'headline' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $headline ); ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'text' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Text:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'text' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'text' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $text ); ?>" />
        </p>


        <?php 
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("kevintext");') );


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing your description correctly. Really, you aren't passing it at all.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::WP_Widget(false, $name='Kevins Textbox');
    array('description' => __('A text widget created by Kevin Ullyott for practice in creating widgets') );
}
```

That 'description' line is creating an array but you aren't doing anything with it. It is just floating alone in space. You need to pass that to `WP_Widget`. [Follow the example in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Example):

```
/**
 * Register widget with WordPress.
 */
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'foo_widget', // Base ID
        'Foo_Widget', // Name
        array( 'description' => __( 'A Foo Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
    );
}
```

See how ID, name, and the array all get passed to the parent constructor? Compare that to your code, where the array is outside the closing bracket of `WP_Widget`.

Calling `WP_Widget` is about the same as calling `__construct`-- [the first passes everything to the second](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/widgets.php#L76). `WP_Widget` is a pre-PHP5 style constructor as noted in the source.

Also, no need to assign the name to a variable here, `$name='Kevins Textbox'`. You can't 'name' variables when you pass them [like you can in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495031/python-passing-parameters-by-name).

So, what you need is this:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::WP_Widget(
    // or parent::__construct(
        false, 
        'Kevins Textbox',
        array(
            'description' => __('A text widget created by Kevin Ullyott for practice in creating widgets') 
        )
    );
    ;
}
```

You need [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to get your posts.

```
$fiveposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 5);
var_dump($fiveposts); // should show you what you have to work with.
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can set description of a widget like this:

Create a __construct function.

Then create variable for widgets options like **Description**, class, id of the widget.

```
    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array(
                'description' => __('Your Widget description goes here'),
                'classname' => 'your_widget_class',
                'id' => 'your_widget_id'
            );
        parent::__construct('your_widget_id_backend', 'Your Widget Title', $widget_ops);
    }
```

Call parent class (WP_Widget) construct function.

parent::_construct passes 3 parameters. **First** parameter passes the html widget id, which should display on backend under Widget section. **Second** parameter passes the widget title and **Third** parameter passes the array of options you set earlier with variable **$widget_ops**.

To get your most recent posts. You can try this.

```
$loop = new WP_Query('showposts=5&order=DESC');

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;
```

The above code will output 5 recent posts title.